# Referenciar entidades internas de un agregado en otro agregado

Tags: java, backend, diseño-de-clases, ddd

En mi afán de implementar DDD me ha surgido la duda al querer hacer referencia a una entidad dentro de un agregado desde otra entidad interna de otro agregado. Estas son las clases de las que dispongo:

```
public class Grupo{
    private GrupoId id;
    private String name;
    private Integer horasTotales;
    private List<Modulo> modulos; //No se pueden crear módulos si no es desde el agreagado ya que contiene una serie de invariantes que se han de cumplir (el numero de horas del listado de módulos no puede superar el numero de horasTotales de Grupo)
}

public class Modulo {
    private ModuloId id;
    private String name;
    private Integer horas;
}
```

Mientras, por otro lado tengo el siguiente AR (Horario) que crea reservas y dichas reservas tienen que hacer referencia a un módulo, que es una entidad interna del anterior AR.

```
public class Horario {
    private HorarioId id;
    private Integer anyo;
    private GrupoId grupoId;
    private List<Reserva> reservas;
}

public class Reserva {
    private ReservaId id;
    private Date horaEntrada;
    private Date horaSalida;
    private ModuloId moduloId;
}
```

Claro está que no se puede hacer referencia a una entidad interna de un agregado desde otro agregado distinto (según los libros de DDD). Por lo tanto, ¿es correcta esta referencia mediante el VO ModuloId desde Reserva que hace referencia a la entidad interna del agregado GRUPO o estoy enfocando mal el problema?

Saludos y Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la relación entre grupos y horarios? Si es uno a uno, quizá deberías unir/fusionar ambas entidades

Comment: El grupo puede tener un horario por año.